# Powershell Cannot index into null array

Tags: powershell

I am running a short script that will go through folders and delete log files older than 14 days on a remote computer:

```
    param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string] $remoteHost = $args[0],
[boolean] $run = $args[1]
)
$rootFolder = '\d$\Projects\';
$folders = 'Folders1\logs\','Folders2\logs\','Folders3\logs\';



foreach($folder in $folders){
    $fullPath = ('\\' + $remoteHost + $rootFolder + $folder + '*.log*');
    if($run){
        Get-ChildItem $fullPath | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-15)} | Remove-Item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
    }
    else{
        Get-ChildItem $fullPath | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-15)} | Remove-Item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WhatIf;
    }
}
```

But, when running the script I am getting the error shown below. Is it because it may be going through some of those folders and is not seeing any files older than 14 days?

```
cmdlet  at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
remoteHost: PRLVWEPMSAP04
Cannot index into a null array.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

Comment: Best solution is to use `Try...Catch` construction to handle empty directories and errors

Comment: `[string] $remoteHost = $args[0]` and `[boolean] $run = $args[1]` -- The assignments don't make any sense, what are you trying to accomplish with them? Maybe to make sure that `$run` will be the 2nd positional argument? This isn't necessary, PowerShell automatically assigns positions in the order of the arguments (you _may_ change the positions using the `Position` attribute only).